# Compact Framework 3.5 Update Usercontrol With Main Form Variable Data

Tags: user-controls, compact-framework

This seems like it should be simple, however, I cannot find an example through searching...
How do I update a label on a usercontrol using variables from its parent form?

I am building a compact framework 3.5 application.

Thanks for any and all assistance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a public property on the user control, and you update your label from there, for example:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get
        {
            return label1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also return the label itself, although some people may say that would break encapsulation on your design.